Error in your cron job
Good morning. I have a CRON stuck because it fails to run due to this error.
How can I avoid it and where should I intervene?
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (H****_mag2new.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video, CONSTRAINT FK_6FDF205946906B0E653E60AA769899F8 FOREIGN KEY (value_id) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity_media_gallery ), query was: DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE (value_id = '1913671126' )

what cron is this? it looks like you are cleaning up some media elements, buy the video is not deleted before deleting the media galery entry

Please also translate your title to English, per Stack Exchange requirements.

@Vito Lanave
Hey, please look at the following steps:

Check Cron Configuration
Check Cron Schedule
Check Cron Logs
Check File Permissions
Review Cron Job Code
Check Log Errors
Run Cron Manually
Check PHP Version &&  Clear Cache

Thank You!

As your error message that there are dependent records in the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video table that reference the value_id you're trying to delete.
solution depend on what you trying achieve with your cron action
if you want to delete the record. first you need to delete the dependent records first before deleting the parent record. for that you can add below direct sql query for check parent dependency and delete it.
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$valueId = '1913671126'; // Example value_id, replace with dynamic fetching logic

try {

    $connection->beginTransaction();

    // Delete dependent records
    $connection->delete(
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video',
        ['value_id = ?' => $valueId]
    );

    // Delete parent record
    $connection->delete(
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery',
        ['value_id = ?' => $valueId]
    );


    $connection->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    $connection->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}

